# PHP Notice Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be receiving a number of php notices advising 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

I assume it is the way I have structured the mysql statement but I am a little unsure and I am after assistance here.

The function is as follows:-

```
public function getPreviousBlock($iHeight=0) {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT height
        FROM " . $this->block->getTableName() . "
        WHERE height < ?
        ORDER BY height DESC
        LIMIT 1");
    if ($this->checkStmt($stmt) && $stmt->bind_param('i', $iHeight) && $stmt->execute() && $result = $stmt->get_result())
        return $result->fetch_object()->height;
    return $this->sqlError();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which line is the error on? Which variable is it trying to get the property from?

Comment: This line = return $result->fetch_object()->height;

Comment: Why do I feel everytime I ask a question on stackoverflow I get the good old 'Possible duplicate' which never helps me.

Comment: What is inside `$result`? Have you checked with `is_object($result)`, if it is really an object?

Comment: It should just return a number. What do you mean is_object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch_object()` will return NULL if there are no more rows in the result set. Of course NULL is not an object so you will get this error.

So you need to check for example:

```
$obj = $result->fetch_object();
if ($obj) {
   return $obj->height;
} else {
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Does this look correct?`public function getPreviousBlock($iHeight=0) {
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare("
        SELECT height
        FROM " . $this->block->getTableName() . "
        WHERE height < ?
        ORDER BY height DESC
        LIMIT 1");
    if ($this->checkStmt($stmt) && $stmt->bind_param('i', $iHeight) && $stmt->execute() && $result = $stmt->get_result())
        $obj = $result->fetch_object();
  if ($obj) {
   return $obj->height;
  } else {
   return null;
  }
    return $this->sqlError();
}`

Comment: I think it should be like this ```function getPreviousBlock($iHeight = 0)
{
    $stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare(" SELECT height FROM " . $this->block->getTableName() . " WHERE height < ? ORDER BY height DESC LIMIT 1");
    if ($this->checkStmt($stmt) && $stmt->bind_param('i', $iHeight) && $stmt->execute() && $result = $stmt->get_result()) {
        $obj = $result->fetch_object();
        if ($obj) {
            return $obj->height;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return $this->sqlError();
}
```